# Why won't Firefox accept my certificate?

Tags: tls, openssl, firefox

I've been trying to get `stunnel` to work with my signed certificate (with a CA that I've trusted in Firefox). The error is:

> 127.0.0.1:5559 uses an invalid security certificate.
>   The certificate is only valid for 127.0.0.1
>   Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

However, `127.0.0.1` is in alternative DNS names. Here is my OpenSSL config file:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
CN = chacheserver.net
[v3_req]
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = chacheserver.net
DNS.2 = *.chacheserver.net
DNS.3 = *.*.chacheserver.net
DNS.4 = *.*.*.chacheserver.net
DNS.5 = 192.168.1.130
DNS.6 = 192.168.1.70
DNS.7 = 192.168.2.130
DNS.8 = 192.168.2.70
DNS.9 = 192.168.8.70
DNS.10 = 192.168.8.130
DNS.11 = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I think that your error appears because your cert is signed to another domain.

Comment: That config file puts SAN in the *CSR*; are you sure you copied it to the *cert*? Does `openssl x509 -noout -text -in certfile` show the SAN values (assuming you have or get it in a file)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to mark your IPs with type `IP.` (instead of type `DNS.`).

Namely, make your section look like this:

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = chacheserver.net
DNS.2 = *.chacheserver.net
DNS.3 = *.*.chacheserver.net
DNS.4 = *.*.*.chacheserver.net
DNS.5 = 192.168.1.130
DNS.6 = 192.168.1.70
DNS.7 = 192.168.2.130
DNS.8 = 192.168.2.70
DNS.9 = 192.168.8.70
DNS.10 = 192.168.8.130
DNS.11 = 127.0.0.1
IP.1 = 192.168.1.130
IP.2 = 192.168.1.70
IP.3 = 192.168.2.130
IP.4 = 192.168.2.70
IP.5 = 192.168.8.70
IP.6 = 192.168.8.130
IP.7 = 127.0.0.1
```

Some broken browsers (older Internet Explorers, I think) actually expect IPs to be marked "DNS". So for backwards compatibility you can leave the IPs marked as they are and ALSO add them marked with type ID "IP".

#### Further reading

- General SAN concept with OpenSSL: ApeTec, 2012-01-15, [*Multiple Names on One Certificate*](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm). (Archived [here](https://archive.is/gGdVc).)
- Broken browsers:

  - MichaelM.Info: [*IP addresses in SubjectAltName in SSL website certificates #fail for some browsers*](http://www.michaelm.info/blog/?p=1281). (Archived [here](https://archive.is/Z96aH).)
  - Microsoft Connect regarding this: [ID869717](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/869717/ie-all-versions-ie-does-not-use-ipaddress-as-a-subject-alternative-name-in-ssl-certificates-which-prevents-the-use-of-name-constraints)

#### Sidenote: Multiple wildcards will probably not work.

I don't think many clients will accept more than a single wildcard.

So they will probably accept these:

```
DNS.1 = chacheserver.net
DNS.2 = *.chacheserver.net
```

But reject these:

```
DNS.3 = *.*.chacheserver.net
DNS.4 = *.*.*.chacheserver.net
```

Comment: Ad "you can leave the IPs marked as they are": Beware that Firefox will consider these "DNS" records invalid and ignore rest of the SAN (see https://serverfault.com/a/1101182). If you must have these records, please make sure they are on the end.

Answer (score 4):

You've added `127.0.0.1` to your alternative DNS for the certificate, but `127.0.0.1` is an IP address, not a domain name. The DNS field requires the use of a domain name, which means the client does a lookup on the domain name of the IP and gets `localhost`. Since this doesn't match (`"127.0.0.1" != "localhost"`) you get the mismatch error.

The field you're looking for is `subjectAltName`. This allows you to set alternative common names (CNs) including IP addresses.

Comment: there is already subjectAltName = @alt_names

Comment: @BaselSayeh I'm not sure that works. Try explicitly providing them in the `subjectAltName`.